# What is w.fn.init[0]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

From time to time (normally when my code is wrong), I get to see this object reference in the developer console:

`w.fn.init [form#addOnListFilters.form-horizontal]`

The way I'm getting this message in the console is by submitting a form, and I have the following Js code:

```
   $('form[method="get"]').on('submit', function () {
                console.log($(this));
            });
```

I'd like to know where is this w.fn.init thingy coming from to learn about it, but I don't know where to search it in the jQuery doc.

Comment: It is coming from the line, ```console.log($(this));``` and the result you see is the value of ```$(this)```..

Comment: `w` seems to be some minified code. Try using non-minified. `fn.init` seems to be init function

Comment: it probably refers to `jQuery.fn.init` after minification

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I know, the console.log is intended, I want to see the content of the form, but im getting that w.fn.init thing where I can't see nothing rn

Comment: @adiga 
that's it, thanks! Now my problem is that I don't know why I can't see the form data in the console, but the question was solved.